# iniciar servicio de icecast con php

Tags: php, linux

Solicito que alguien me pueda dar una orientación adecuada a lo que intento hacer.  Bueno, me explico.

Quiero iniciar el servidor icecast2 por medio de php,(sabemos que inicia solo por defecto para un solo puerto) pero  en mi caso quiero controlar por ejemplo el purto 8002, 8004, 8006  darle start desde php.

esta misma función lo he hecho con shoutcast, y con shoutcast si me inicia y detiene el server.

sería algo así en un vps, teniendo en cuenta que para icecast estaría en: `/home/icecast/8002` y sucesivamente...

en shoutcast lo tengo así...

`/home/shoutcast/9002`   y demas puertos... como lo inicio y detengo en shoutcast? sencillo.

creo 2 archivos:

1. on.ph  el cual tiene el siguiente código:

```
shell_exec('./sc_serv9002');
header('Location: "ruta deseada despues de ejecutar comando');
```

o también llamando un archivo llamado start9002.sh con permisos 777 que contiene la ruta de iniciar shoutcast  (`/home/shoutcast/9002/sc_serv  /home/shoutcast/9002/sc_serv.conf`)

```
shell_exec('./start9002.sh');
header('Location: "ruta deseada despues de ejecutar comando');
```

2. el off.php (que apagará el puerto shoutcast especifico así.

```
shell_exec('killall sc_serv_9002');
header('Location: "ruta deseada despues de ejecutar comando');
```

De esa manera controlo los puertos de shoutcast. He intentado hacer lo mismo con icecast, pero no lo consigo.  Porque quiero hacerlo así, para evitar estar accediendo a consola y ejecutar cada uno manual como lo sería con este comando `/home/icecast/8002/init.d/icecast2 start`   Cabe destacar que esa no es la ruta predeterminada para iniciar icecast, ya que la original es:  `/etc/init.d/icecast2 start`   pero como he creado mis carpetas para cada puertos, solo puedo iniciarlos por consola y quiero usar php para iniciarlo llamando el archivo start8002.php de icecast por medio de un botón.

cabe destacar que  probé el codigo que me imprimiera el resultado y me mando como respuesta que el comando se ejecutó e imprimió que icecast estaba iniciando. Pero no inicia.

plataforma de dessarrollo, VPS con **UBUNTU 18.4 y ubuntu 20**

gracias al que pueda darme una mano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que estás usando concretamente y cuál es el error?

Comment: el codigo que he usado en en el on.php es ***shell_exec('/home/icecast/9002/init.d/icecast2 start');
header('Location: "ruta deseada despues de ejecutar comando');*** intente llamar in start.sh desde php en el cual start.sh tenga la ruta de inicio como consola /home/icecast/9002/init.d/icecast2 start  y tampco funciona ni aunque llame el archivo desde el on.php con shell_exec usando el comando que lo inicia o ./start.sh

Comment: en la pagina principal esta el botón que se encargará de llamar el archivo php que devería iniciar el icecast.  este es el codigo del boton ***<form action='on.php' method= 'post' >
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="ON RADIO" />
           </div>                      
      </div> 
</form>*** y el codigo del php on es: ***shell_exec('/home/icecast/9002/init.d/icecast2 start'); header('Location: "/index.php');***

Comment: La verdad es que no logro entender cuál es el problema. Sugiero que revises el log de errores de PHP en busca de un mensaje de error en concreto que puedar darte pistas de lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: No hay archivos logs 